# Is there any documentation for clang source code?

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm starting a project on clang. I might add some code to clang source code. I got source from git but don't know where to start. 
Is there any documentation for clang source code?
Thanks.

++ I tried to find some way to add additional features on clang, and found LibTooling and its tutorials(https://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example/). This may help!

Comment: So isn't there enough information on the project web site ?

Comment: @auburg The source is large, and the official site seems to have general information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The clang documentation is automatically generated similar to LLVM. You can, for example, find the documentation for Clang-9 as of this writing here [Doxygen for clang-9](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/)

As stated by Valeriy Savchenko in the comment of this post. There is also a [manual for Clang internals](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html) available.